# Spring Integration doesn't allow negative lookbehind

Tags: java, regex, spring-integration

I'm using spring-integration-file to monitor a folder. I need to ignore files that have .inprogress as the file extension. The problem is the regular expression `^(.*(?<!\.inprogress))$` includes a character that's not allowed in the inbound-channel-adapter. Using it throws an exception

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "filename-regex" associated with an element type "file:inbound-channel-adapter" must not contain the '<' character.

Is there another way I can write the expression so that it doesn't use the '<' character or is there another way around this limitation?

I'm using the following:
spring-integration-file 2.0.5.RELEASE
Java 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid **negative lookbehind** by this **negative lookahead** regex:

```
^(?!.*\.inprogress$)(.*)$
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pN6tI8/2)

Comment: Thank you for you help and for introducing me to that tool. I like that it explains what things are doing. :)

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you need to declare a `<` in a String in the XML, use `&lt;`.